# Java - using JAMA to create a 3by3 matrix with random values

Tags: java, matrix, jama

this is what I have got so far...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random= new Random();
        Matrix mR = new Matrix(3,3,random.nextDouble()) ;
        System.out.println("Here is a 3x3 matrix with random values " +Arrays.deepToString(mR.getArray()));

    }
```

The problem is when I print this out, all of the values are the same. What I need is different value in each index. I know this can be done simply by creating an array, assigning it random values, then copying that into the matrix. But I need to do this straight from the matrix mR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Random.nextDouble` returns a `double`, so in the code above you are calling this constructor:

```
Matrix(int m, int n, double s)
```

Which constructs a m-by-n constant Matrix.

You should just call this static method instead:

```
public static Matrix random(int m, int n)
```

E.g.,

```
Matrix mR = Matrix.random(3, 3);
```

See the [doc](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/) for more information.